# Python print the nth character of every string in a list?

Tags: python

Ive created some code that for now just adds strings to a list till the user decides to quit, and then it returns the first value of that list.

```
wordList = [] 

while 1:
    user_input = input("Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): ")
    if user_input=="QUIT":
        break
    wordList.append(user_input)
    
    for i in wordList:
        newList = wordList[0]
    
print ("list of characters: " + str(newList))
print()
```

however, what I require is to be able to print the nth character of each word. So for example if n was 5 the following you return

```
Enter a word (or type Q to quit): A
Enter a word (or type Q to quit): ABCDE
Enter a word (or type Q to quit): wollongong
Enter a word (or type Q to quit): 123456
Enter a word (or type Q to quit): frog
Enter a word (or type Q to quit): Q
List of characters:
['E', 'o', '5']
```

Comment: newList.append(wordList[i][4]). Only if len(wordList[i])>=5

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```py
wordList = [] 

while 1:
    user_input = input("Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): ")
    if user_input=="QUIT":
        break
    if len(user_input) > 4:
        wordList.append(user_input[4])
    
print ("list of characters: " + str(wordList))
print()
```

```
Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): A
Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): ABCDE
Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): wollonglong
Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): 123456
Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): frog
Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): QUIT
list of characters: ['E', 'o', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there but it looks as if you're getting confused a little with the [] notations. If you have a variable followed by squared brackets it selects the position. So for example lets look at your list called wordList.

```
print(wordList[0])
```

the output would be "A".

```
print(wordList[1])
```

the outbut would be "ABCDE"

The same applies to strings (words/numbers here for you). So if you're just wanting to print out the 5th letter of a string you can use myString[4] (little confusing but [4] is the 5th letter as 0 counts). Using this logic if we look at your loop.

```
for i in wordList:
    newList = wordList[0]
```

this doesn't make too much sense are you are just setting a variable called newList equal to the 1st input of wordList over and over again. If I were to solve this problem I would use a loop to first find out if words are larger than 5 characters, if they are add them to a new list. And then use another loop to print out the nth character of every input of the new list we just created. Have a little go if this makes anymore sense and let me know if you need anymore help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to save the nth element of the list and not the first:

```py
wordList = [] 
n = 5
while 1:
    user_input = input("Enter a word (or type QUIT to quit): ")
    if user_input=="QUIT":
        break
    wordList.append(user_input)
    
    for i in wordList:
        if len(newList) > n:  # check if your list has more than n elements
            newList = wordList[n]  # store the nth element
    
print ("list of characters: " + str(newList))
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = []
for word in wordList:
    if len(word) >= 5:
       result.append(word[4])
```

And result[] will be having the 5th character(here you specified 5) for each of the word in wordList.

So generally if we need nth character

```py
result = []
for word in wordList:
    if len(word) >= n:
        result.append(word[n - 1])
```